# Bootstrap tool tip not styled correctly?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I added a bootstrap tool tip to a font-awesome image. The tool tip comes up like it should but it is not styled correctly in my opinion. This is my first time to use a BS tool tip and based on examples I have found it should have a nice style to it.

I'm using LESS and have imported the bootstrap in. I can see the tool tip styles when I look at my compiled CSS file. I have bootstrap.js imported into the page as well through bundling. I think this is a CSS issue more than a .js issue.

Here is the code at the top of my LESS file where I import in BS and font-awesome.

```
@import "LESS/bootstrap/bootstrap";
@import "LESS/font-awesome/font-awesome";
```

Here is from my bundle.cs file.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));
```

Here is some of the style for the tool tip from my compiled .css file. This was added from BS through the LESS complilation.

```
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1070;
  display: block;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  line-break: auto;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: left;
  text-align: start;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: none;
  text-transform: none;
  white-space: normal;
  word-break: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

This is in my Razor view.

```
<i class="fa fa-clock-o icon-2x clock-status-online" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Clock Online"></i>
```

This is my custom CSS to style the font-awesome image.

```
.clock-status-online{
    color: forestgreen;
}
```

This is a screen shot of what it looks like. The one on the left is my tool tip that is just a basic box. The one on the right is from an example article and my assumption is that this is what a tool tip should look like out of the box.

[image]

Comment: Did you enable Tooltips as per Bootstrap's documentation?  They are opt-in meaning that you do need to include a bit of jQuery: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

Comment: Yes, I have the JS to call the Tooltip. The Tooltip is displaying like it should, it's just styled differently than I thought it would be.

Comment: It would be useful to see a functional example, perhaps on JSFiddle or Bootply.  Bootstrap 3 doesn't render tooltips in the fashion indicated on first image, nor does Bootstrap 4.  If that rendering isn't the result of the default browser appearance taking precedence the most likely culprit is some other CSS being applied.